# Calculating the number of related contacts

Tags: formula, custom-field, roll-up-summary

Can anyone assist me in coming up with a formula/roll up summary for the Account object that will give a numerical value from calculating the number of related contacts

Comment: This is harder than it seems at first sight because a roll-up summary field can't be created across this relationship. So triggers have to be used; see e.g. [Trigger for Contact count on Account giving Exception: Too many code statements: 200001](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000093azIAA) and the various answers. If your org has large numbers of Contacts, you are also in danger of hitting the 50,000 "Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries" [governor limit](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Declarative Rollup Summary Tool](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56365/calculating-the-number-of-related-contacts), which was created by the CTO of FinancialForce and is a free utility which enables you to create rollup summaries really neatly across master-detail and lookup relationships declaratively.

You can find more information on this here: https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries.

The declarative lookup rollup summary you would want in order to achieve the # of contacts per accounts is:

Lookup Rollup Summary Name: 'Number of Contacts per Account' 
Parent Object: Account
Child Object: Contact
Relationship Field: AccountId
Field to Aggregate: Id 
Aggregate Operation: Count
Aggregate Result Field: Number_of_Contacts__c
Active: Yes
Calculation Mode: Realtime
Calculation Sharing Mode: User

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can achieve this declaratively, if there is  then i would be interested myself :)

The alternate method would be to write a trigger on contact object to update the realtime count value of related contacts.

```
/* Provide summary of Number of Contacts on Account record */

trigger ContactSumTrigger on Contact (after delete, after insert, after undelete,
after update) {

    Contact[] cons;
    if (Trigger.isDelete)
        cons = Trigger.old;
    else
        cons = Trigger.new;

    // get list of accounts
    Set<ID> acctIds = new Set<ID>();
    for (Contact con : cons) {
            acctIds.add(con.AccountId);
    }

    Map<ID, Contact> contactsForAccounts = new Map<ID, Contact>([select Id
                                                            ,AccountId
                                                            from Contact
                                                            where AccountId in :acctIds]);

    Map<ID, Account> acctsToUpdate = new Map<ID, Account>([select Id
                                                                 ,Number_of_Contacts__c
                                                                  from Account
                                                                  where Id in :acctIds]);

    for (Account acct : acctsToUpdate.values()) {
        Set<ID> conIds = new Set<ID>();
        for (Contact con : contactsForAccounts.values()) {
            if (con.AccountId == acct.Id)
                conIds.add(con.Id);
        }
        if (acct.Number_of_Contacts__c != conIds.size())
            acct.Number_of_Contacts__c = conIds.size();
    }

    update acctsToUpdate.values();

}
```

Note: This code is taken from http://www.ericsantiago.com/eric_santiago/2009/12/contactscases-rollup-for-accounts-in-salesforce.html. The credit for this code goes to the author

Hope this helps